# Deleting lines in multiple files

Tags: c#, file, line

I'm tring to remove an old header located in my files that is compound from 3 lines of text.
So far i did the job but i cant make this work for more than a file...

What i've tried:

```
string line = null;
string line_to_delete =     "-------------------------------" 
    + Environment.NewLine + "-- VSO2 CE " 
    + Environment.NewLine + "-------------------------------";
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("dir"))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file))
        {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (String.Compare(line, line_to_delete) == 0)
                continue;

                writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: you're reading/writing to the same file at the same time?

Comment: as you can see i need to read/write... it's there a better way to do it?

Comment: I would write it to a new file then delete the old file and rename the new file to the old file before you loop again in your foreach.

Answer (score 0):

How about refactor to something like this:

```
const string Delim = "-------------------------------";
const string SomeText = "-- VSO2 CE ";
foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles("dir")) 
{
    var first3Lines = File.ReadLines(filePath).Take(3).ToList(); 
    if(first3Lines.First() == Delim && 
       first3Lines.Last() == Delim && 
       first3Lines[1]==SomeText)
    {
        //this file's first 3 lines matches what you want.
        //now write something somehow.
        //it wasn't super clear what you want to write or do.     
        //leave a comment if you want help with that.
        DeleteLines(filePath, 3);
    }                    
}


private void DeleteLines(string filePath, int numLines) {

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath + "-new.txt")) {
        while (numLines-- > 0) { reader.ReadLine(); }
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the following method: `line = reader.ReadLine()`, which will read the line (up to the end of it), and will never match the `line_to_delete`, which contains 3 lines.

How do you expect it to match them ? :)

If you know they are the header, and they are always in top, how about using `File.ReadAllLines().Skip(3)`, and just writing that back into the file?